# Replace kitchen base unit under quartz worktop

Tags: replacement, kitchen-counters, mdf, quartz

Can I replace a kitchen base unit without affecting the rest  of the kitchen? It’s a 1000mm unit on legs, on the end of a 2600 stretch. There’s an end panel on the left, a built in oven and hob to the right and a quartz worktop. The bottom of the base unit has got wet at the front and due to the very poor wrapping the MDF has blown. So I think I have to replace the whole unit.

Comment: Are the legs height-adjustable?

Comment: What is "the bottom" of the unit?  Usually what gets water damaged is just a kickboard that's clipped to the legs and easy to replace.  Or is it the floor of the cabinet that's ruined?

Comment: There's a high probability that the counter top was adhered to the top of the cabinet in question with caulk or construction adhesive. This will make pulling a single cabinet unit out of a bank rather difficult if the countertop runs the full length. If it stops at the hob and only covers the cabinet in question, though, that will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, the trick is finding all the screws. Usually a pair of cabinet connectors at the front which go all the way though and then a pair of regular screws at the back, look inside the cabinet or the adjacent cabinet.

The end panel might be tricky, ideally you could remove the screws from inside the cabinet and leave the end panel in place to hold up the worktop. Especially if it's been 'siliconed' to the flooring and/or the worktop.

It helps if the cabinets are on adjustable legs as you can wind them up and let gravity help you determine when all the screws are out.

Interesting you say the cabinet is MDF, I've not seen that before. Normally the cabinets themselves are a laminate wrapped particle board (chipboard in the UK).
Doors are sometimes wrapped MDF though.

Comment: Tip, seal the internal bottom corners and 15cm up each back corner with clear silicone in the new cabinet...  then should anything leak in the cabinet it won't get into the bare board.

Comment: Sometimes quartz worktop are glued on.